# jQuery checkbox gallery select

Tags: jquery, select, checkbox, gallery

How can I create a JQuery function for the following?

When I checked the images I want to click the button and copy that images to another  for working with that selected images.

Here is the sample I made, but it's not working good:

```js
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('input[name="obrazky"]').click(function () {
                    getSelectedCheckBoxes('obrazky');
                });

                var getSelectedCheckBoxes = function () {
                    var result = $('input[name="obrazky"]:checked');
                    if (result.length > 0) {
                        var resultString = result.length + " checkbox checked<br/>";
                        result.each(function () {
                            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                            resultString += selectedValue + " - "
                                + $('label[class="obrazek' + selectedValue + '"]').html() + "<br>";
                        });
                        $('#showselected').html(resultString);
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#showselectedk').html("No checkbox checked");
                    }
                };
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="obrazek1"><input type="checkbox" name="obrazky" class="filled-in" value="1"><span></span><img alt="" height="100" width="100" src="https://tvorbawebu.net/eshopserver/uploads/Pentair-Led-Pool-Lights.jpg"></label>   
       <label class="obrazek2"><input type="checkbox" name="obrazky" class="filled-in" value="2"><span></span><img alt="" height="100" width="100" src="https://tvorbawebu.net/eshopserver/uploads/f823888da14805caf9a229986595f06c.jpg"></label>
       <label class="obrazek3"><input type="checkbox" name="obrazky" class="filled-in" value="3"><span></span><img alt="" height="100" width="100" src="https://tvorbawebu.net/eshopserver/uploads/Downunda-perimeter-overflow-pool-raised-spa-fire-bowls_490.jpg"></label>
       

        <div id="showselected"></div>
```

I wanna make like Wordpress files library, where you can choice your file and put in the main post thumbnail.

Thank you for help.

Comment: SIr, can you please explain when you select those images what do you want to do next? It doesnt state clear in your description. Also can you please create this example in jsfiddle.?

Comment: Hi, here is code: https://jsfiddle.net/6j4dwouq/

I want to "copy" and "paste" that images without any codes and inputs...

Comment: Is this what you want https://jsfiddle.net/tnLymacq/ ?

Comment: Yeah! Thats it! :) Thank you so much man, you really helped me.

Comment: SHOULD I ADD IT AS A ANSWER FOR YOU TO ACCEPT IT?

Comment: Im new in here, I dont know what you mean :)

Comment: I have added an answer just click tick to mark it as answered.   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[name="obrazky"]').click(function () {
            getSelectedCheckBoxes('obrazky');
        });

        var getSelectedCheckBoxes = function () {
            var result = $('input[name="obrazky"]:checked');
            if (result.length > 0) {
                var resultString = result.length + " checkbox checked<br/>";
                result.each(function () {
                    var selectedValue = $(this).val(),
                        $lbl = $('label[class="obrazek' + selectedValue +'"] img');
                    resultString += selectedValue + " - " + $lbl.clone().wrap('<div/>').parent().html() + "<br>";
                        
                });
                $('#showselected').html(resultString);
            }
            else {
                $('#showselected').html("No checkbox checked");
            }
        };
    });
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tnLymacq/